# How to find the ASN of an IP using "dig" command?

Tags: 14.04, ip

How do I find what autonomous system number or name an IP address belongs to?

Could I find it using Ubuntu's `dig` command?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Under what autonomous system number or name that an IP is located? How to find it using "dig" command in Ubuntu?

<strike>[`dig`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/dig.1.html) is a DNS client and DNS doesn't contain any information about Autonomous System Numbers.</strike>  However, you can use [`whois`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/whois.1.html) to query for this purpose.

Syntax: `whois -h whois.cymru.com " -v [IP_ADDR]"`

It helps to use quotes and put a space in front of the `-v` option.

[image: whois_query]
*Click to zoom in on the image*

UPDATE in CY 2022:
I'm not sure how long cyrmu has ASN info available through DNS records, but they obviously do now.  I lined-through my DNS ASN answer above.  Please refer to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1397114/14618) to get ASN info via `dig` from cymru.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can with (free) services like `cymru.com`.

For instance, to query the IP `216.90.108.31` with `dig`:

```
dig +short 31.108.90.216.origin.asn.cymru.com TXT
```

The result would be:

```
"23028 | 216.90.108.0/24 | US | arin | 1998-09-25"
```

Where `23028` represent the ASN

---

**EDIT**

BTW if you wanna just the AS number:

```
$ dig +short 31.108.90.216.origin.asn.cymru.com TXT | tr -d \" | cut -d\  -f1
23028
```